# Swipe gesture not working on UIView in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gestures

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeHandle:)];
rightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[rightRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeHandle:)];
leftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[leftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];
```

I have added swipe gestures on viewDidLoad method, I have multiple view which swiped left and right, on views contain table, when table have data, left and right gestures working fine, but when in case of empty table gestures are not working.

Any suggestion.. ?

Note: Its working in simulator but not on device.

Comment: Please add <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> in .h file and do not forgot to set delegate rightRecognizer.delegate = self and leftRecognizer.delegate = self.

Comment: userinteraction should be enable of your view.

Comment: [self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer]; replace self.view with your table name.

Comment: @ChiragPipaliya It would not work if table is empty, i want gesture on view.

Comment: @pratikbhiyani user interaction is enable of view.

Comment: Finally my code is working..!! 

I've set UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, implemented shouldReceiveTouch delegate, while debugging i noticed that shouldReceiveTouch getting called multiple times. 
There is one more delegate shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer, which used to allow multiple gesture recognition. i just returned yes here, Now my coding working well.

Comment: Put your code as answer and accept it, so that other users can get benefit of it.

Comment: The problem may be because I've added two gestures, Finally one  delegates helped me. Now code is working.

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
  
    return YES;
}

Answer (score 7):

The problem may be because I've added two gestures, Finally one delegates helped me. Now code is working.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
     { 
        return YES; 
     }
```