# Single swipe gesture added from Storyboard on UIView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a UIView on which I have to perform different action based on the gesture performed by the user.

I have applied following Gestures:

- UITapGestureRecognizer for ONE touch and TWO touch which works properly and call its action as well.
- UISwipeGestureRecognizer for all directions, i.e. Right, Left, Up,
  Down with ONE touch and TWO touch.
- TWO touch UISwipeGestureRecognizer also works properly and call its action as well.
- But I have a problem with the **ONE touch UISwipeGestureRecognizer which never works in any condition.**

Please help me for the solution.

Comment: Can you please post here some code?

Comment: I have added all gestures through storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

Please check below image.

[image]

Your swipe gesture should have configurations as shown in the image.

Comment: Yes, I have the same configuration.

Comment: Please take a look at this question :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591455/swipe-gesture-not-working-on-uiview-in-ios?rq=1

Comment: Following code work for me:`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestur‌​eRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer { return YES; }`